# Question on the usage of "taking into consideration"

Tags: grammar, grammaticality

I am inquiring the correct usage of "taking/taken into consideration" in the following context:

> We leave it as one future work to XXX, given the identified issues and also taking randomness into consideration.

Or

> We leave it as one future work to XXX, given the identified issues and also taken randomness into consideration.

Which one is correct? Thanks for a lot!

Comment: It should be *taking randomness into consideration*.

Comment: I note "and also" has fifty-percent redundancy. It would be alright to just use one, it may be preferable to not use either. I find it difficult to imagine what XXX could be that would make the rest of the first clause acceptable. The second clauses are, apart from the location of the carriage return, identical. Come to that so are the first, what's the question again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Phr. to take into consideration, under consideration.**  [OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/39602?redirectedFrom=take%20into%20consideration#eid8594576)

As in your example (commenting on the tense, not the entire grammatically of the sentence):

> ... and also **taking** randomness **into consideration**.

and

*It may be fairly cheap to buy, but have you taken into consideration the money you'll spend on repairs?*